# InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException when calling the CreateTrail operation with API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-organizations

I am trying to [configure an AWS Organizational trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/creating-trail-organization.html) in my master account and failing with bucket policy error.
Details:
The guide i am following is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-and-update-an-organizational-trail-by-using-the-aws-cli.html

The CLI is IAM user that have S3FullControl and CloudTrailFullControl for testing purposes.
Creating the trail is done with this simple command:

```
aws cloudtrail create-trail --name inna-org-trail --s3-bucket-name   bucket-inna-org1 --is-organization-trail --is-multi-region-trail
```

I get back this Error:
**An error occurred (InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException) when calling the CreateTrail operation: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket:** bucket-inna-org1

I tried to add permissions to the user but it doesn't change anything.

The bucket policy is standard AWS textbook stuff and listed below. can anyone tell me what is missing here please?

> {
> "Version": "2012-10-17",
>
> ```
> "Statement": [
>     {
>         "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20201",
>         "Effect": "Allow",
>         "Principal":  "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com",
>         "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
>         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-inna-org1" 
>     },
>     {
>         "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20152",
>         "Effect": "Allow",
>         "Principal": "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com",
>         "Action": "s3:PutObject",
>         "Resource": [
>             "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-inna-org1/master/AWSLogs/464372413802/*",
>             "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-inna-org1/AWSLogs/273925183535/*",
>             "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-inna-org1/AWSLogs/375700267666/*",
>             "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-inna-org1/AWSLogs/769509352908/*"
>         ],
>         "Condition": {
>             "StringEquals": {
>                 "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
>             }
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20173",
>         "Effect": "Allow",
>         "Principal": "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com",
>         "Action": "s3:PutObject",
>         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-inna-org1/AWSLogs/o-eadh1jbx7l/*",
>         "Condition": {
>             "StringEquals": {
>                 "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ] }
> ```

Any suggestion/direction would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved the issue:

It seems the missing S3 bucket policy permissions for cloudtrail were the following **Actions**, and the **Resource** required broader bucket permission "/*"

```
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObject"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-inna-org1/*"
```

Next, I discovered that the bucket directory path pertaining to the organizational directory is different from what I used initially, using the "master" account prefix in the organization, rather than the organization prefix ( o-eachljbx71 )

```
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-inna-org1/master/AWSLogs/464372413802/*"
```

I hope this helps someone out there!

Comment: Only the PutObject action requires that prefix?