# how to solve InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException error message

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am creating a Cloudtrail and referencing an exisisting S3 bucket with policy that was created manually.I am getting an error when i do terraform apply.below is my code for the cloudtrail resource and the current S3 bucket policy that was created manually.please help

```
resource "aws_cloudtrail" "data_event_trail"{
  name                           = var.trail_name
  s3_bucket_name                 = var.cloudtrail_data_event_log_bucket_name
  s3_key_prefix                  = var.organization_id
  enable_log_file_validation     = true
  kms_key_id                    = var.kms_key_data_arn

  event_selector {
    read_write_type           = "All"
    include_management_events = false

    data_resource {
      type   = "AWS::S3::Object"
      values = ["arn:aws:s3:::${var.cloudtrail_data_event_log_bucket_name}"]
    }
  }

  tags = var.default_tags
}
```

exisiting bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cloudtrail-data-event-logs"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cloudtrail-data-event-logs/AWSLogs/123456789012/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```
error message:
```

```
Error: Error creating CloudTrail: InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket: cloudtrail-data-event-logs
```

Comment: yes the link took me back to my question

Comment: Policy before resource might help(if not already this way). https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6388#issuecomment-313124026

Comment: If you are trying to create a organization trail, the resource require broader bucket permissions. Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64866292/9347057